# What is the Sun's absolute direction called?

Tags: coordinate

Like the Sun's direction relative to the local standard of rest is called "solar apex"

What term can I google instead to find info about the Sun's direction relative to the CBBR?

I understand considering the movement of our galaxy we are moving toward Vega.

But I want to find our net direction, considering all factors - the motions of our galaxy, local group, galaxy cluster, etc

All considered, which way are we headed? Or what is the name of this, so I can know which term to search.

Comment: ["the particular motion of our Galaxy through the universe!"](https://nightsky.jpl.nasa.gov/docs/HowFast.pdf)